# Simulating the error "more columns than column names" for testing purposes

Tags: r, knime

So I'm using R through KNIME which usually is fantastic, however it's somewhat tricky to troubleshoot within the KNIME environment.  I can't easily just copy and paste my R code into RStudio as it depends on various KNIME variables that I need to reproduce/simulate.  I'm getting a frustrating error that I am having a hard time crushing.

The gist of it is that the code is grabbing a CSV from a website, then is just formatting it for the output.  Here's the problem area:

```
  csv = getURL(paste("https://www.website.com/", knime.flow.in[["report"]],"?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv&", knime.flow.in[["extrai"]], sep=""), curl=curl)

  r <- read.csv(text = csv)
```

This almost always works great.  But the odd thing is if I have several streams of this code running in a loop.  When it's run one by one it almost always works.  But when it's run concurrently it almost always errors out.  Here's a pic:

[image: Knime Workflow]

So, that's the background.  What I'm thinking of doing is just throwing a loop together in R that checks for the "Error: more columns than column names" and if so, repeat the loop until it works.

How do I, with R, detect this error?